# Unable to send keyevents for navigation keys on 3rd party applications

Tags: firefox-os, firefox-marionette, gaia

I am doing automation on Firefox OS (Gaia) on a feature phone using [marionette](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Intro.html) in Python.

#### Problem

I am not able to simulate hardware keyevents for the navigation keys and other selection keys on some applications (see in code `"ApplicationName"`).
However I am able to use them on native apps.

#### Code

Below is my code snippet:

```py
#creating marionette client on port 2828
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828)
client.start_session()
#import js script to launch app by name
js = os.path.abspath("/usr/local/script.js")
client.import_script(js)
result=client.execute_async_script("GaiaApps.launchWithName('%s')" % "ApplicationName")
client.switch_to_frame(result.get("frame"))
num = "123456"
client.find_element('css selector','input[type=text]').send_keys(num)
#Above code is working fine

#below code is not working on some thirdparty applications
client.execute_script("window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'ArrowDown', keyCode: 40}))")

#closing the client
client.close
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: found any solution ?